# Kivy: Differentiating between editing widget text in GUI and Python

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

I'm making a GUI using Kivy that updates text in other widgets based on when text in the first widget changes.

So for example, in my .kv file I have something like this:

```
Spinner:
  id: spinner1
  on_text: root.update1()
  text: 'blah'
  values: ...
Spinner:
  id: spinner2
  on_text: root.update2()
  text: 'blah'
  values: ...
```

Then in my Python script I've got something along the lines of this:

```
class MyClass():
...
  def update1(self):
    self.ids.spinner2.text = 'some new text'
    # do more stuff
  def update2(self):
    # do stuff
```

Basically I want to update spinner2's text to reflect the properties of an object I have selected with spinner1, and that seems to work fine.

The issue is, when I change the text of spinner2 in my update1 function, spinner2 will then call its associated callback function (update2) because the text has changed. Because of the way I have things setup having the extra callbacks doesn't seem to have much of an effect, but I'd like to reduce how many times I'm calling these functions. Does anyone know of a way to specify to the *on_text* property whether the change is coming from Python or the GUI? Or will I be forced to run the callback, and then check inside of there?